# Plotting points with different colors using corresponding list of labels

Tags: matplotlib, machine-learning

I have the following matrix and vector of labels:
The idea is to plot the points within points according to the labels (1 and -1) in y. assume the calculation of the function true_label works.

```
 M = [5, 10, 15, 25, 70]
 for m in M:
    points = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.zeros(2), np.eye(2), m)
    true_labels = true_label(points)
    y = np.where(true_labels, 1, -1)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    colors = ['green', 'red', 'blue']
    plt.plot(points, c=y, cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors))
    # red is 1, blue is -1
    plt.show()
```

However I can't seem to get this to work.. 
`AttributeError: Unknown property cmap`
is what I keep getting. I've updated matplotlib so I dont really understand why this doesnt work. Any advice on how to get this done easily?

Comment: `plt.plot` does not support colormapping. Possibly you meant to use `plt.scatter` instead?

Comment: Hi, I used scatter and yes that seems to do the trick, thank you.